# Centering cards on screen

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I followed a unity tutorial to make a memory game but after adding more cards, they now go off the right of the screen.

The code uses a single card in the Unity designer and all other cards are instantiated and positioned from that (using startpos)

```
public const float offset = 2.5f;
Vector3 startpos = originalCard.transform.position;

for (int i = 0; i < numCols; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < numRows; j++)
    {
        card = Instantiate(originalCard) as MemoryCard;
        float posX = (offset * i) + startpos.x;
        float posY = - (offset * j) + startpos.y;
        card.transform.position = new Vector3(posX, posY, startpos.z);
    }
}
```

I would like to center the cards in the screen but not sure how given that the screen dimensions via Screen.width are in pixels but the Vector code is not and the x component of the original card (startpos.x) is actually negative.

Comment: Instead of calculating and setting UI positions manually you might want to have a look at [HorizontalLayoutGroup](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-HorizontalLayoutGroup.html) and [VerticalLayoutGroup](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-VerticalLayoutGroup.html)

Comment: I haven't done it recently and don't remember exactly how I done it before but have you tried Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint(), and using Screen.height/width (or Camera.main.pixelheight) to calculate the input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way is to move the original card in your scene view. If you click your camera u can see it's bounds so click the camera, then move you starting card as far left as you can and still see it.   If they still don't all fit in camera, you can change the card width and do some math to see how many cards you can fit.

The alternative solution, but also easy, is to adjust your camera bounds to encompass the cards where they are.

Comment: But my background is only a certain size and I would like the cards to be right in the center of the scene.

Comment: you can make the background bigger. try this first though, make the background a child of camera, (drag it onto the camera in the inspector) then just move your cam a little bit. hit play, see how far off you are, hit stop, adjust camera.   if you still cant get all the cards to fit you will need to make them smaller, or your background larger, and since the background is just one image it makes sense to scale that instead of fifty cards.